# How to generate a unique id automatically for the data that is posted to an API server using axios library in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I have a redux-form which is used to receive data from the user and post it to a back-end API server.While posting data to the server,I want to generate a unique id for each set of data that is being posted to the server, so that I can use the id later for referencing that particular set and displaying it to the user.So,how to generate that unique id automatically while posting a set of data to the server?

The code for my **redux-form** is given below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createPosts } from '../actions/posts_action';

class CreatePost extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectValue : ''
  };
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.renderCategory = this.renderCategory.bind(this);
}

  renderField(field) {
      return(
        <div className="title-design">
            <label className="label-design"> {field.label} </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="title-input"
              {...field.input}
            />
            <div className="text-help  has-danger">
              {field.meta.touched ? field.meta.error : ''}
            </div>
      </div>
      );
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const value=e.target.value;
    this.props.change("categories",value);
    this.setState({selectValue: value}, () => {
      console.log(value)
    });
  }

  renderCategory(field) {
    return(
      <div className="title-design">
        <label className="label-design">{field.label} </label>
          <Field name="category" className="title-input" component="select">
            <option></option>
            <option value="react">React</option>
            <option value="redux">Redux</option>
            <option value="udacity">Udacity</option>
          </Field>

          <div className="text-help has-danger">
            {field.meta.touched ? field.meta.error : ''}
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

    onSubmit(values) {
      this.props.createPosts(values, () => {
          this.props.history.push('/');
      });
    }



    render() {
      const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

      return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
          <Field
            label="Title for Post"
            name="title"
            component={this.renderField}
          />

          <Field
            label="Post Content"
            name="body"
            component={this.renderField}
          />

          <Field
            label="Category"
            name="category"
            component={this.renderCategory}
            />



          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          <Link  to="/">
            <button className="cancel-button">Cancel</button>
          </Link>
        </form>
      );
    }
}

function validate(values) {
  const errors = {} ;

  if (!values.title) {
      errors.title = "Enter a title";
  }

  if (!values.body) {
    errors.body = "Enter some content";
    }

  if(!values.category) {
    errors.category = "Please select a category";
  }

  if (!values.id) {
      errors.id = "ID not generated";
  }

  return errors;
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate : validate,          //validate
  form : 'CreatePostForm'
})(
  connect(null,{ createPosts })(CreatePost)
);
```

The **action creator** for creating a new post is given below:

```
//Action Creator for creating posts
export function createPosts(values, callback) {

  return dispatch => {
    return axios.post(`${API}/posts`,values,{headers})
      .then((data) => {
        callback();
        console.log(data)
      dispatch({
        type: CREATE_POST,
        payload: data
      })
    })
  }
}
```

**Reducer** for creating the post:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { FETCH_POSTS, FETCH_POST, CREATE_POST } from '../actions/posts_action';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POST:
      // const post = action.payload.data;
      // const newState  = { ...state,  };
      // newState[post.id] = post;
      // return newState;
      return {...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload};

    case FETCH_POSTS:
     return {posts: { ...state.posts, ...action.payload }};

    case CREATE_POST:
      return {posts: { ...state, ...action.payload}};

     default:
      return state;
  }

}
```

So,how to genrate the id for each set of data that is sent to the server?

**Edit 1:**

I am trying to add the uuid on my onSubmit() method as shown below,but it doesn't work.I sit not how it should be done or I have to do it some other way?

```
  onSubmit(values) {

          this.props.createPosts(values, () => {
            uuidv1();
          this.props.history.push('/');
      });
    }
```

**Edit 2:**

Sever file for posts:

```
const clone = require('clone')

let db = {}

const defaultData = {
  "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd": {
    id: '8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd',
    timestamp: 1467166872634,
    title: 'Udacity is the best place to learn React',
    body: 'Everyone says so after all.',
    author: 'thingtwo',
    category: 'react',
    voteScore: 6,
    deleted: false,
    commentCount: 2
  },
  "6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez": {
    id: '6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez',
    timestamp: 1468479767190,
    title: 'Learn Redux in 10 minutes!',
    body: 'Just kidding. It takes more than 10 minutes to learn technology.',
    author: 'thingone',
    category: 'redux',
    voteScore: -5,
    deleted: false,
    commentCount: 0
  }
}

function getData (token) {
  let data = db[token]
  if (data == null) {
    data = db[token] = clone(defaultData)
  }
  return data
}

function getByCategory (token, category) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    let posts = getData(token)
    let keys = Object.keys(posts)
    let filtered_keys = keys.filter(key => posts[key].category === category && !posts[key].deleted)
    res(filtered_keys.map(key => posts[key]))
  })
}

function get (token, id) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    const posts = getData(token)
    res(
      posts[id].deleted
        ? {}
        : posts[id]
    )
  })
}

function getAll (token) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    const posts = getData(token)
    let keys = Object.keys(posts)
    let filtered_keys = keys.filter(key => !posts[key].deleted)
    res(filtered_keys.map(key => posts[key]))
  })
}

function add (token, post) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    let posts = getData(token)

    posts[post.id] = {
      id: post.id,
      timestamp: post.timestamp,
      title: post.title,
      body: post.body,
      author: post.author,
      category: post.category,
      voteScore: 1,
      deleted: false,
      commentCount: 0
    }

    res(posts[post.id])
  })
}

function vote (token, id, option) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    let posts = getData(token)
    post = posts[id]
    switch(option) {
        case "upVote":
            post.voteScore = post.voteScore + 1
            break
        case "downVote":
            post.voteScore = post.voteScore - 1
            break
        default:
            console.log(`posts.vote received incorrect parameter: ${option}`)
    }
    res(post)
  })
}

function disable (token, id) {
    return new Promise((res) => {
      let posts = getData(token)
      posts[id].deleted = true
      res(posts[id])
    })
}

function edit (token, id, post) {
    return new Promise((res) => {
        let posts = getData(token)
        for (prop in post) {
            posts[id][prop] = post[prop]
        }
        res(posts[id])
    })
}

function incrementCommentCounter(token, id, count) {
  const data = getData(token)
  if (data[id]) {
    data[id].commentCount += count
  }
}

module.exports = {
  get,
  getAll,
  getByCategory,
  add,
  vote,
  disable,
  edit,
  getAll,
  incrementCommentCounter
}
```

Comment: Generally its the reponsibility of the server to generate the unique id and pass its with the response data

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri When I try to create a new post,I do not see any "id " property for the post.I have pasted the server file above in an edit.Can you please have a look at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, normally you'd let the server generate that id, then send it back down as part of the response for the axios call, but if you really want to generate an ID on a client, I suggest using uuid and one of it's various UUID generators:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

example from the docs:

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
uuidv4(); // -> '110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1'
```

You've added more code, and I think you're better served using uuidv4() on your server; something like:

```
function add (token, post) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    let posts = getData(token)
    let id = uuidv4();

    posts[id] = {
      id: id,
      timestamp: post.timestamp,
      title: post.title,
      body: post.body,
      author: post.author,
      category: post.category,
      voteScore: 1,
      deleted: false,
      commentCount: 0
    }

    res(posts[id])
  })
}
```

This way, the id is generated on the server.  The client no longer needs depend on uuid, and you're not "trusting" the client to generate a valid id.  The id would render back to the client as part of the response, and you could then use it from the client when doing edits, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Let me try it out.Will update you the outcome in few mins.

Comment: I tried adding the uuidv1() in my onSubmit method after importing it,but I don't see it added.I have added the code in an edit above.Can you please have a look at it and let me know how to proceed?

Comment: I thought you wanted to submit the id?  You're just calling the method, not using the resulting ID value.  You might want to add the result of uuidv1() to the values being pushed, so that the server can then send it right back as part of the result.   "values[id] = uuidv1();" BEFORE you make the axios call.

Comment: okay,will try it the way you suggested.Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Is there any difference using an unique uuid or just a counter like redux docs (https://redux.js.org/basics/example#actions-indexjs)?

Comment: @Rashomon  Yes, there is... each time your redux code is restarted (when you redeploy, or whatever), your counter goes back to 0, and you get duplicates of the ones you created last time.

Comment: @billjamesdev I suppose thats in case you are using persisting redux data. Right? Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @Rashomon I kind of assumed the primary reason for generating the ID was to store the object in a DB of some kind and be able to reference it later.  If it was just a temporary identifier (like a session) then your counter would work.  After all, that's what DB sequences do.